# Как воспроизвести креш ios приложения?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Всем привет.
Есть ios приложение которое отлично работало, после обновления xcode до 8.3 скомпилировал и выпустил новую версию.
У пользователелей c ios 10.2 стал происходить креш, я символизировал его но не могу понять в какой конкретно строчке проблема и в чем причина. На симуляторе 10.2 проблема не воспроизводится.

Еще странно то что креш происходит в контроллере в который я не вносил изменения в этом обновлении.

Буду раз любым мыслям.

Креш:

```
Incident Identifier: D0644CB8-F2C4-4490-8F6C-B70C758620D3
CrashReporter Key:   1998f18953bb233373e80a49a3cc0e33a7879964
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:         ExamenPdd [494]
Path:            /var/containers/Bundle/Application/9A03D02B-0AD3-482C-802A-904CBB88E58F/ExamenPdd.app/ExamenPdd
Identifier:      com.mezhevikin.ExamenPdd
Version:         1.0.4 (2)
Code Type:       ARM-64
Parent Process:  ? [1]

Date/Time:       2017-04-05 19:18:41.000 +0300
OS Version:      iOS 10.2 (14C92)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000 at 0x0000000ed144beb0
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100705f04 swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional (__hidden#19254_:291)
1   ExamenPdd                       0x0000000100037c70 specialized QuestionTableView.favoriteButtonTapped(UIButton) -> () (TicketViewController.swift:771)
2   ExamenPdd                       0x0000000100034fe4 @objc TicketViewController.scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(UIScrollView) -> () + 52
3   UIKit                           0x000000019124bd30 0x191207000 + 281904 (<redacted> + 96)
```

Код на который указывает крэш:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код надо добавлять текстом, а не картинкой. Покажите метод `deleteFromFavorites()`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте **"Embedded Content Contains Swift Code"** установить **YES**, по умолчанию он имеет значение NO. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а также  установить , **Runpath Search Paths** значение **@executable_path/Frameworks**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Привет. Спасибо за ответ, можно подробнее что это за параметры и почему они могут мне помочь? Я проверить к сожалению не могу. Мне не удалось воспроизвести проблему на симуляторе с той же ios. Крэши получаю из аналити

Comment: я посмотрел, у меня эти параметры ровно так и были как вы советуете, так что можете не объяснять

Answer (score 0):

У тебя ошибка в 771 строчке. Переходи в метод

```
question.deleteFromFavorites()
```

И ищи там ответ на свой вопрос, либо выкладывай на всеобщее обозрение...